# How to integrate matrices (Sum of Matrices with dx spacing) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, statistics, gaussian, numerical-integration, integral

I'm pretty confused on how I would go about summing an infinite amount of matrices in MATLAB. Lets say I have this function (a gaussian):

```
%Set up grid/coordinate system

Ngrid=400;
w=Ngrid;
h=Ngrid;

%Create Gaussian Distribution

G = zeros ([w, h]);
Sig = 7.3; %I want the end/resultant G to be a summation of Sign from 7.3 to 10 with dx 

for x = 1 : w
    for y = 1 : h
        G (x, y) = exp (-((Sig^-2)*((x-w/2+1)^2 + (y-h/2+1)^2)) / (2));
    end
end
```

I essentially want the end/resultant function G to be a summation of Sign from 7.3 to 10 with dx (which is infinitesimally) small ie integration. How would I go about doing this? I am pretty confused. Can it even be done?

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to actually be summing `G` over a range of `Sig` values. You never change the value of `Sig`. In any case, assuming that `dx` isn't too small and that you have the memory this can be done without any loops, let alone two.

```
Ngrid = 400;
w = Ngrid;
h = Ngrid;

% Create range for Sig
dx = 0.1;
Sig = 7.3:dx:10;

% Build mesh of x and y points
x = 1:w;
y = 1:h;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

% Evaluate columnized mesh points at each value of Sig, sum up, reshape to matrix
G = reshape(sum(exp(bsxfun(@rdivide,-((X(:)-w/2+1).^2+(Y(:)-h/2+1).^2),2*Sig.^2)),2),[h w]);

figure
imagesc(G)
axis equal
```

This results in a figure like this
[image]

The long complicated line above can be replaced by this (uses less memory, but may be slower):

```
G = exp(-((X-w/2+1).^2+(Y-h/2+1).^2)/(2*Sig(1)^2));
for i = 2:length(Sig)
    G = G+exp(-((X-w/2+1).^2+(Y-h/2+1).^2)/(2*Sig(i)^2));
end
```